# TikZ image breaks PDF printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pdf

I have a strange conundrum. I created this image in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black!30!white,line width=0.1mm] (0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--cycle;
\fill[red] (0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--cycle;
\fill[yellow, path fading=north] (0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--cycle;
\draw[color=black!30!white,line width=0.1mm] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\fill[yellow] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\fill[blue!20!green, path fading=east] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.9,0.1732)--(0.8,0)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\draw[color=black!30!white,line width=0.1mm] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\fill[red] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\fill[blue, path fading=north] (0.1,0.1732)--(0.4,0.692)--(0.6,0.692)--(0.2,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine with PDFLatTeX, and the screen output is perfect.

However, when I go to print the PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI, it gives me an error:

"This document could not be printed", and then "There were no pages selected to print"

I removed the image from the document, and the document printed fine. 
I tried to print the image on its own, and it did not print. I went digging through the PDF "preflight" settings. There is no broken PDF syntax; that checks out. The best I can figure out is that the colors in the image are causing some sort of problem, as flattening them to sRGB works through Acrobat, but I don't know how to fix that at compile time so I don't have to edit it in Acrobat.

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: I've never had one not print at all. But I wouldn't necessarily expect an image with a `fading` to print correctly. At least, they generally don't for me.

Comment: Beautiful colours, though. You could convert the image to PNG or PDF and try including that with `\includegraphics`. I don't know it will work, but it might. You can also try converting the PDF document to PS and back to PDF with ghostscript, but this will make the file huge and probably break the fading.

Comment: Strange. On my 20-years  old PostScript HP LaserJet (black-and-white, 4p/min) I get it within a few seconds, printing from SumatraPDF.

Comment: Works for me too (Canon 3530).  Of course its only .32in by .28in.

Comment: Prints fine for me (from evince).

Comment: I can print this as well from another program. I'm specifically looking for some sort of pre-processing that will allow it to be printed from Acrobat Pro, as that is what the printer will be using.

Comment: Fadings and shadings are relatively new PostScript operations that are created on the fly. New printers tend to handle these relatively OKish but old or non-PS printers and non-Acrobat PDF viewers deal with these in a wide spectrum of success. One of the reasons for this is that they fall back to rasterizing the image as you do with flattening. So that the rendering is done on the software rather on the printer. Acrobat assumes full functionality but your driver says otherwise hence the problem.

Comment: I've never had a problem rendering this kind of thing in Okular. (Although there are some cases Okular does not render correctly.) But printing is another story. In those cases, I've just kludged something i.e. gotten around the inability to print the fading by using a simpler construct of some kind, even if not exactly what I had wanted.

Comment: Since you know what works within Adobe, you could look for a PDF tool which can do the same thing either to just the image or to your document as a whole. Maybe something like pdftk (no longer maintained, mores the pity) or qpdf or similar. Or even something like ImageMagick. These are all command line processors. I don't know which, if any, can do what you need. But I'd try thinking along those lines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a 'TeX end' issue (as demonstrated by preflight checking).